# How do I customize the position of ngx-bootstrap datepicker for mobile view?

Tags: css, angular, datepicker, angular8, ngx-bootstrap

I am using two ngx-bootstrap datepickers side by side in an Angular 8 project. In mobile view, both the datepickers are going out of the viewport as shown below. What do I do to position both the datepickers in the centre of the mobile screen?[I am getting this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WchH8.jpg)
But [I need this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoF5o.jpg) for both the datepickers. I can achieve this output if I put `left: 23%` as already `position: absolute` is assigned for the datepicker. But It changes the position of both the datepickers. I want both the datepickers to be placed in the centre of the screen. These are the styles that are already present in the datepicker by default: `display: block; position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(-42px, 149px, 0px); z-index: 1080;`

Comment: can you provide stackblitz

Comment: Hi @TalhaAkca, you can try this link, [NGX Boostrap Datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#basic). On clicking this link, you will get the link for the stackblitz link for a basic datepicker. In the stackblitz link, you will find one datepicker and one daterangepicker. Please help me to change the positions of the datepickers individually.

Comment: Its ok...My problem is solved

Comment: Hello @DhritimanTamuliSaikia, I am also facing the same kind of issue, can you please share your code as an answer. Really thank.

Comment: Hello @GaneshJangam, is your issue solved?

Comment: In styles.css, put these styles...  ```  bs-datepicker-container{
    transform: scale(1,1) !important;
    top: 118px !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    width: fit-content !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    }  ```  In place of the `top: 118px !important`, put your position accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In styles.css, put these styles...
`bs-datepicker-container{ transform: scale(1,1) !important; top: 118px !important; left: 0 !important; right: 0 !important; width: fit-content !important; margin-left: auto !important; margin-right: auto !important; }`
In place of the top: 118px !important, put your position accordingly.